# loading jqGrid that uses grouping with new data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which I load with JSON Data from a Java Spring backend. We do this for some jqGrids already, but I have added grouping to this new grid. So far it just groups one level, and on the initial load it does this fine.

Later we will allow the user to change one field in a row, we don't need editing other than that, and that will be a popup with a list of values to choose from.

The problem shows up when the user enters new search parameters and clicks the search button -- the system takes the parameters and returns a new dataset, which I then want to appear in the (or a) grid just as the first dataset does. My first little test dataset was 3 records, the search I've been testing with returns 9 records; what the grid does is display 3 of the nine records in the places where the three original records appeared. I note that the groupings are still in place and are then wrong, i.e., the groups no longer reflect the data.

I finally set grouping:false on the jqGrid setup parameters; then the 3 records appeared correctly without grouping, and the 9 records also appeared correctly. I tried setting grouping:false before the searched data was put in the grid and setting it back afterwards, but that still leaves me with 3 of 9 records displayed. So what I'm doing at the moment is:

```
function processSearchSubmit() {
    // show the dialog indicating a new search is underway.
    $(".progressDialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        title: 'Progress Dialog',
        modal: true,
        width: "550px",
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        dialogClass: 'dlg-no-close'
    });
    $(".progressDialog").dialog('open');

    setTimeout(function() {     // we set a timeout so that IE will display the progress dialog just opened
        $.ajax({
            url: "/blah/blah/getDataList",
            type:'POST',
            data: {searchDetails:getSearchDetails()},
            dataType: 'json',
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            async: false,
            error: function(xhrInstance, status, e){
                //alert("error data got back; status ==>" + status);
                console.log("error data got back; status ==>" + status);
                console.log("error data got back; e ==>" + e);
                $(".progressDialog").dialog('close');
                return false;
            },
            //process the response. send event to parent to refresh the whole screen.
            success: function(gridData){
                var listGrid = $('#listGrid');

                $('#listGrid').clearGridData(true);
                $('#listGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {grouping: false});
                $('#listGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData.rows});
                $('#listGrid').trigger('reloadGrid');
                listGrid.jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', "salesManager",
                                                    {
                         groupColumnShow: [true]
                        ,groupText: ["<b>{0}</b>"]
                        ,groupOrder: ["asc"]
                        ,groupSummary: [true] // will use the "summaryTpl" property of the respective column
                        ,groupCollapse: false
                        ,groupDataSorted: true
                        ,formatDisplayField: [function(curValue, srcValue, colModelOption, grpIndex, grpObject) {
                            return srcValue.toFixed(2);
                        }]
                    }
                );
                $('#listGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {grouping: true});

                $('#listGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {userData:gridData.userdata});        // set filterText into param on grid

                // because 'search' is implemented as an ajax call returning its 'gridData', the
                // "filter text description" (a string describing search parameters, such as "Last 60 days, created by rcook")
                // is obtained from that data with the following statement. When the list page is loaded
                // with the initialization of the grid itself ($("#listGrid").jqGrid(getGridSettings());, where
                // getGridSettings() uses a URL to obtain JSON data to load the grid), we use the jqGrid 'userData'
                // parameter to store the filter text, and therefore other code loads this string differently.
                $("#filterTextDesc").html(gridData.filterTextDesc);

                $(".progressDialog").dialog('close');
            }
        });
    }, 1);
```

This is in addition to the grouping specs on the initial jqGrid setup as well, of course.

What I'm looking for is an easier way to do this. This way, I'll have to duplicate the grouping settings, once at jqGrid setup and another time any time the data changes. I'd really like to have ONE place where I can put JSON data into the grid -- right now I return one JSON structure the first time the grid is loaded and another one when the user does a search. But I'll take a simpler solution fo the grouping issue by itself, if one's available.

---

I've tried the solution from Oleg's comment, and am seeing the same thing; when the grid is first loaded, it has 3 records, grouped as I expect. When I do a new search with the backend and attempt to reload the grid with the new data, the gropuing headers stay in place, and the three records are replaced with 3 of the 9 records returned in JSON to the 'success' option on the Ajax call. I've tried two things for reloading:

```
                var listGrid = $('#listGrid');
                var params = listGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam");
                params.data = gridData.rows;
                listGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

and

```
                var listGrid = $('#listGrid');
                listGrid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'local', data: gridData.rows}, true);
                listGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

and they both have the same effect as each other, and the same as I was getting before when I was using "setGridParam" incorrectly. I'd welcome other ideas.

Also: stopping in the Firefox JS debugger after the "setGridParam" call, gridData shows as an object with 'rows' and 'userdata' fields, and the rows field shows an array of 9 objects. gridData.rows[0] shows a row with the newly loaded info. When I step past 'clearGridData()' the grid on the browser empties, and when I step past "reloadGrid" the old data appears on the grid.

Comment: If you need to replace `data`, then you should never use `$('#listGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData.rows});`. Instead of that you should either use one more parameter of `setGridParam` with the value `true` or to use `getGridParam` instead of `setGridParam`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691924/315935) for more details. Additionally, please write always **the version** of jqGrid, which you use, and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I did not give the version. We're using the old 4.7 version that was still free. I will check this out later tonight or tomorrow (dinnertime in my time zone now).

Comment: This still didn't work. I'm editing the question with more details.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you because you post too few information. First of all, **you didn't posted** JavaScript code, which creates the grid. Do you use `grouping`? Is the grid grouped by other column as `salesManager`. Has the grid `pager`? Which value has `rowNum`? and so on. Seconds, I can't follow the code of `$.ajax.success` callback. Why you use `setGridParam` here? Do you want to hold grouping or not? You trigger `reloadGrid` *before* some other changes, which will be not applied (`userData`) ... It would be helpful if you post more full code related to jqGrid and post test data.